# Autocompletion for my python module using click

Tags: python, autocomplete

I created a python module I install.
It uses a Bash CLI commands such as `my-module init` or `my-module delete`.

The structure is like:

```
my-module/
|--- setup.py
|--- my_module
|    |--- __main__.py
|    |--- delete.py
|    |--- init.py
```

`setup.py`

```
setuptools.setup(
    name="my-module",
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "my-module = my_module.__main__:cli"
        ]
    },
```

`__main__.py`

```
@click.group(chain=True)
def cli():
    pass


cli.add_command(init_cmd)
cli.add_command(delete_cmd)
```

`init.py`

```
@click.command("init")
@click.option("-p", "--path",
              type=str,
              help="Path to the project workspace."
              )
def init_project_cmd(path):
    pass
```

It works correcly, however, the autocompletion does not work.
It does work for `my-module` but not for the second part.

Following [this](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/8.1.x/shell-completion/) I edited `.bashrc` adding the line:

`eval "$(_ML_PIPELINE_COMPLETE=bash_source /path/to/my-module/my_module/__main__.py)"`

However, (after running `chmod` to `__main__.py` because I had a permission error) I have the error messages saying

```bash
import-im6.q16: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/359.
from: can't read /var/mail/my-module.delete
from: can't read /var/mail/my-module.init
/path/to/my-module/my_module/__main__.py: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/path/to/my-module/my_module/__main__.py: line 9: `from some_module import ('
```

My quesitons:

1. Am I on the good track? What am I missing then? The errors looks very weird and it feels like the autocompletion should be easy.
2. If so, now I have to (at least), to add a line to bashrc, with the path to the main file (that I don't really know because each user will have their own path to python packages). How can I automate this so that it is done with the `pip install` command?

Comment: did you add shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3` in first line of your script? If you don't have it then `bash` may treats your python script as a bash script - and then it treads command `import` as program `import` from `imagemagic` to make screenshot (and text `import-im6.q16` in error confirm it). Or you have to use directly  `python` to run it `bash_source python  /path/to/my-module/my_module/__main__.py` a

Answer (score 1):

Error shows that system treats you `python script` as a `bash script`.
It treats function `import` (in your code) as program `import` (also available as `import-im6.q16`) from package `imagemagick` which is used to make screenshots.

---

You may have to use directly `python` or `/full/path/to/python` in command

```
eval "$(_ML_PIPELINE_COMPLETE=bash_source  python  /path/to/my-module/my_module/__main__.py)"
```

(and this doesn't need to use `chmod`)

---

Or you have to add `shebang` `#!/usr/bin/env python` in first line of your script - and bash will know that it has to use `python` to run this code.
(Linux doesn't use extension `.py` to recognize language but it uses `shebang` for this)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# ... code ...

@click.group(chain=True)
def cli():
    pass

cli.add_command(init_cmd)
cli.add_command(delete_cmd)
```

(and this also needs to use `chmod`)

(`#` = `she`, `!` = `bang`, `#!` = `shebang`) (Wikipedia: [Shebang (Unix)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: Well I tried. It seems to work in the sense that I have no longer any error. But the autocomplete does not work anyway :s I was probably not on the right path.